# Why am I seeing unreliable behavior using USBSer.dll in Embedded Compact 7, what do my errors mean?

Tags: c++, embedded, usb, windows-ce, usbserial

Hopefully someone can help me or atleast shed some light on the errors I am seeing :-).

Our WEC7 platform is required to communicate with a number of devices over USB Serial.

To enable this I have added to our OS, UsbSer.dll and the relevant registry settings for the devices, this works fine and the driver is loaded when a device is inserted.

The communication with the devices is unreliable:

To be clear, when WEC7 boots and successfully communicates I can disconnect, reconnect and reset **the Device** as many times as I like and still communicate reliably.

When WEC7 boots and can’t communicate properly there is nothing I can do other than a **full WEC7 reboot** hoping it will communicate successfully the next time.

Debugging has pointed to some errors seen when first opening the COM port:

Here is a **working output** showing opening\setting up of the Serial Port:

```
PID:057600AA TID:04DC00D2 Creating Serial Port
PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 !USBD:CloseTransfer, invalid handle
PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 !USBD:CloseTransfer, invalid handle
PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 !USBD:CloseTransfer, invalid handle
PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 !USBD:CloseTransfer, invalid handle
PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 UsbAsyncClassPipe::ResetPipe(fForce=1PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 EHCD:          CQueuedPipe(Bulk)::ClearHaltedFlag - warning! Called on non-stalled pipe
PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 EHCD:  CQueuedPipe(Bulk)::ClearHaltedFlag on QHead c9f779c0, token 00000040
PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 !USBD:CloseTransfer, invalid handle
PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 +UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0x300,1024,0xce4a0000, dwClientInfo=fedd0000PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 - UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0xce4a0000,0x7c3b000, return=1PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 +UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0x300,1024,0xce4a0400, dwClientInfo=fedd0001PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 -UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0xce4a0400,0x7c3b400, return=1PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 +UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0x300,1024,0xce4a0800, dwClientInfo=fedd0002PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 -UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0xce4a0800,0x7c3b800, return=1PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 +UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0x300,1024,0xce4a0c00, dwClientInfo=fedd0003PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 -UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0xce4a0c00,0x7c3bc00, return=1PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 UsbAsyncClassPipe::ResetPipe(fForce=1PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 EHCD:  CQueuedPipe(Bulk)::ClearHaltedFlag - warning! Called on non-stalled pipe
PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 EHCD:  CQueuedPipe(Bulk)::ClearHaltedFlag on QHead c9f77540, token 00000040
PID:00400002 TID:04A201AA +UsbAsyncClassPipe::WaitForTransferComplete:-1,dwClientInfo=fedd0000PID:00400002 TID:04DC00D2 !USBD:CloseTransfer, invalid handle
```

When **not working** this sequence is almost identical besides the last line, followed by some errors and transfers, not seen in the working output:

```
PID:021200E2 TID:028F0082 Creating Serial Port
PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 !USBD:CloseTransfer, invalid handle
PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 !USBD:CloseTransfer, invalid handle
PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 !USBD:CloseTransfer, invalid handle
PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 !USBD:CloseTransfer, invalid handle
PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 UsbAsyncClassPipe::ResetPipe(fForce=1PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 EHCD:  CQueuedPipe(Bulk)::ClearHaltedFlag - warning! Called on non-stalled pipe
PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 EHCD:  CQueuedPipe(Bulk)::ClearHaltedFlag on QHead c9f770c0, token 00000040
PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 !USBD:CloseTransfer, invalid handle
PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 +UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0x300,1024,0xc9fa0000, dwClientInfo=fedd0000PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 -UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0xc9fa0000,0x7670000, return=1PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 +UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0x300,1024,0xc9fa0400, dwClientInfo=fedd0001PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 -UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0xc9fa0400,0x7670400, return=1PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 +UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0x300,1024,0xc9fa0800, dwClientInfo=fedd0002PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 -UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0xc9fa0800,0x7670800, return=1PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 +UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0x300,1024,0xc9fa0c00, dwClientInfo=fedd0003PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 -UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0xc9fa0c00,0x7670c00, return=1PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 UsbAsyncClassPipe::ResetPipe(fForce=1PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 EHCD:  CQueuedPipe(Bulk)::ClearHaltedFlag - warning! Called on non-stalled pipe
PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 EHCD:  CQueuedPipe(Bulk)::ClearHaltedFlag on QHead c9f78740, token 00000040
PID:00400002 TID:048A050E +UsbAsyncClassPipe::WaitForTransferComplete:-1,dwClientInfo=fedd0000PID:00400002 TID:01360022 EHCD:  CQueuedPipe(Bulk)::CheckForDoneTransfers found halted QHead c9f770c0, token 04008140 
PID:00400002 TID:01360022 EHCD:  CQTransfer{Bulk}::DoneTransfer() ERROR: seq #6268, chain #0, qTD #0, token=04008140
PID:00400002 TID:01360022 EHCD:  CQTransfer{Bulk}::DoneTransfer() ERROR: seq #6269, chain #1, qTD #0, token=040081c0
PID:00400002 TID:01360022 EHCD:  CQTransfer{Bulk}::DoneTransfer() ERROR: seq #6271, chain #2, qTD #0, token=040081c0
PID:00400002 TID:01360022 EHCD:  CQTransfer{Bulk}::DoneTransfer() ERROR: seq #6273, chain #3, qTD #0, token=040081c0
PID:00400002 TID:048A050E     
UsbAsyncClassPipe::GetClientInfo return 0xfedd0000PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 !USBD:CloseTransfer, invalid handlePID:00400002 TID:048804D6 
+UsbAsyncClassPipe::WaitForTransferComplete:-1,dwClientInfo=ee21b294PID:00400002 TID:048A050E 
LBUSB: ReceiveInterruptHandler:Transfer Error 4 ,dwLength=0PID:00400002 TID:048A050E UsbAsyncClassPipe::CloseFrontArmedTransfer:dwClientInfo=fedd0000PID:00400002 TID:048A050E 
+UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0x300,1024,0xc9fa0000, dwClientInfo=fedd0000PID:00400002 TID:048A050E -UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0xc9fa0000,0x7670000, return=1PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 
UsbAsyncClassPipe::CloseFrontArmedTransfer:dwClientInfo=fedd0001PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 
+UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0x300,1024,0xc9fa0400, dwClientInfo=fedd0001PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 
-UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0xc9fa0400,0x7670400, return=1PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 
UsbAsyncClassPipe::CloseFrontArmedTransfer:dwClientInfo=fedd0002PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 
+UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0x300,1024,0xc9fa0800, dwClientInfo=fedd0002PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 
-UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0xc9fa0800,0x7670800, return=1PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 
UsbAsyncClassPipe::CloseFrontArmedTransfer:dwClientInfo=fedd0003PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 
+UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0x300,1024,0xc9fa0c00, dwClientInfo=fedd0003PID:00400002 TID:028F0082 
-UsbAsyncClassPipe::BulkOrIntrTransfer:0xc9fa0c00,0x7670c00, return=1PID:00400002 TID:048A050E 
+UsbAsyncClassPipe::WaitForTransferComplete:-1,dwClientInfo=fedd0000PID:01A2000A TID:012C001E
```

If the opening\setting up of the Comm port is the latter sequence, communication will not be successful (We've tried numerous times and could predict if communication will work 100% correctly based on this).

To be more specific on what I mean by not communicating successfully, we can still Tx Serial to the device but not Rx at all (the event EV_RXCHAR is never being fired ), we have proved the device is receiving and responding appropriately.

Would really appreciate any info about the errors or reasons for the behavior we're experiencing. Have we found a bug, has anyone else used UsbSer in WEC7 with no issues?

Thanks in advance,

LB